# How to tie signalR to IoC

Tags: angularjs, sockets, signalr, nancy

I am writing web app in angular, using Nancy as my backend. I have setup signalR websockets as my primary communication mechanism. It works great, with one exception. I can't figure out how to attach state to my socket connection and make it easily available to my code. To be more specific, I can create and maintain state, I am finding it difficult to make that state available to everything on the back end that needs it, without passing a state data object around through every call.
 I was hoping to tie to Nancy's IoC, but that is based off of the session, not off of a websocket. I looked at other IoC systems, but I cannot grok how to tie them to the socket. 
Does anyone have any insight on how to maintain state non-obtrusively with signalR?

EDIT: This may explain it. When the user connects via signalR, I want to create an IGame instance with a life cycle that is tied to the signalR session and inject it throughout my code as needed. for that particular user.

Is that any clearer?

Comment: What is the final end that you are trying to  reach? Concrete domain request, because it may be easier to implement than what you are trying to do:)

Comment: I am writing a web-based roguelike. I need to keep all the state for the current game as the user takes their turns. each turn is a signalR call to the server (I guess it could be a web-route, but the signalR seems to be more flexable and easier.) I can maintain the state with the signalR connection, I just don't want to have to pass it through to ever single method I am calling, or play instantiation games. I would be so much simpler is IoC could handle it. 
Which it probably can I am just not fluent enough in it to set it up

Comment: Ok, so which part are you not able to achieve, injecting a dependency in the hub?

Comment: And what do you understand when you say "SignalR Session"?